# Drupal Commerce Programmatically Complete order and create new cart

Tags: drupal, e-commerce, drupal-commerce, orders

Is there anything i have to do to programmatically complete order and create new cart so the new items is not added to the old order/cart?

Answer (score 0):

There is no new cart or old cart. The cart keeps track of record per user. And for each item you add to cart, there is a record inserted in cart table. If you intend to separate the order per item, you have to write some code. Also try CA

Comment: Thx, what do you mean with CA? Does that that mean to order number? When I add items to cart i have an order number already.

Comment: Its Conditional Access (A type of rules. You can find it under store > configure). You can not have an order number by just adding items to cart

Comment: Strange because when I add an item to the cart an order is created with status cart and can be found under order - shoppings carts.

Comment: You also need to change the status with a query or two. This may involve change the status to 'completed', removing the same from cart and compplet the order programtically. You need to learn about the functions/methods which help you achieving this.